# Is there any way to shorten this sentence? "If we don’t train hard enough this year, we won’t even be able to make it into the semi-final next year."

Tags: sentence-construction

Is there any way to make the sentence below shorter?

> If we don’t train hard enough this year, we won’t even be able to make it into the semi-final next year.

Comment: Sure: If we want to play even in the semi-final next year, we must train hard enough this year.   To reach even the semi-final next year, we must train hard enough this year.  The implication of **even** is that the semi-final is a less ambitious goal than the final.

Comment: Can we make it shorter by replacing “won’t be able to” with “can’t even”?

Comment: Yes, but *won't* is more idiomatic than *can't*  in that particular scenario since the future is explicitly involved.   "We can't make it into the semi-finals if we don't train hard enough."

Comment: If we don’t train hard enough this year, no semi-final next year.

Comment: "be able to make it into" could be replaced by reach, i.e. "won't even reach the semi-final . . ."  Also "this year" is probably redundant, since you already mentioned "next year". It's kind of obvious that the training will be needed before the semi-final.

Comment: Yes, but why are you not Posting your own suggestions?

Comment: "Don't train hard now and we loose chance to semi-final next year" would be my pick. I wonder if its acceptable.

Comment: It would be unusual to refer to the NEXT season in this assemblage. By "next year" I think the writer means "next calendar year, ie, obviously I'm talking about THIS sports season"

Comment: "Want to make it to the semi-finals next year?  No pain, no gain."

Comment: I'm curious about why the OP wants this sentence shortened.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Indeed; the best answer will vary depending on the purpose and/or audience.

Comment: I'm curious why nobody has CVed this. It's an editing request, and not about learning any aspect of English, and which answer is better can only be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Without a specific reason, a *write this sentence using shorter phrases* request seems a mere exercise without purpose. The answer would end up explaining too much, for example that *won't* is more idiomatic than *can't*, *into* can be replaced by *in*, *be able to make it into* can be replaced by *reach*. It's not clear what the OP would learn from the answers, since the way to shorten this sentence does not necessarily apply to other sentences.

Comment: Do it backwards: "Qualifying for next year's semis requires training hard enough this year."

Answer (score 12):

If you're simply looking for fewer words, eliminate the unnecessary ones:

> If we don’t train hard <del>enough</del> this year, we won’t <del>even be able to</del> make it <del>in</del>to the semi-final**s** <del>next year</del>.

OR:

> If we don't train hard this year, we won't make it to the semifinals.

Comment: Removing "next year" makes it sound like you're talking about this year's semifinals though, so I don't think you can remove that part.

Comment: That was partially on purpose. It doesn't make sense to me that you would be training hard this year for the semifinals next year.  Perhaps "next year" refers to a schedule that crosses calendar years, but that's really this year (this season) to me.

Comment: “make it to” can be shortened to “reach”, and “semifinals” to “semis”. And to keep the explicit temporal contrast but cut down length, you could keep “next year”, but replace “this year” with “now”. “If we don’t train hard now, we won’t reach the semis next year.”

Comment: @JohnMontgomery you raise the key point. Indeed as I mention above, *It would be unusual to refer to the NEXT season in this assemblage. By "next year" I think the writer means "next calendar year, ie, obviously I'm talking about THIS sports season"*

Comment: "enough" is not unnecessary. Without "enough" it implies that training to any degree of "hard" is sufficient. I also agree with other @JohnMontgomery that "next year" is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

> If we don’t train hard enough this year, we won’t even be able to make it into the semi-final next year.

I agree with @TimR the significance of *even*. Without that, the target is unclear; readers may think the semi-final is the target.

I feel that *won't even* is a sufficient replacement for *won’t even be able to*.  It is understood that teams taking part in tournaments would want to enter whichever subsequent rounds they are *able to*.  There is no reason why they would choose not to.

> If we don’t train hard this year, we **won’t even enter** the semi-final next year.

Comment: I agree that "even" introduces the notion that the speaker has considered the finals. But I disagree that the finals are the target of this sentence. It's an implication -- its never actually stated, so I don't see how the finals can be the target when only the semifinals are mentioned. The speaker might be dismissing the finals, for example, "Forget the finals. If we don't train hard ..."

Comment: Completely agree with @swmcdonnell   Everyone knows and understands how sports works and when and how the various landmarks take place.

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to sacrifice/shift nuance for extreme brevity:

**Train hard or forget the semi-finals.**

Nuance shifts:

- Assumes the subject of "you" (or an implied "we") is understood.
- Elides any distinction between this year and next.
- Loses the implication by "won't even" that making it to the semi-finals is a sort of minimum goal (that may have been achieved or expected previously).
- Gains impact as a call-to-action compared to more verbose alternatives.

Comment: @Community I really think those sort of comments are uncivil. I don't find the answer unclear. If you do, you should explain how, rather than just posting boilerplate that at least to my eyes comes across as kinda passive aggressive. And to top it off, you're hiding behind the Community account rather than be willing to put your name on it, AND you're posting in response to a new contributor.

Comment: @Community: As it's currently written, your comment is unclear.  Please comment with additional details that will explain what you find unclear about this answer.

Comment: Great answer, good thinking. (The comment at top is bizarre. The "bot" should be deleted.)

Comment: Indeed, @Acccumulation for president.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pare it down to the bare minimum:

> No train, no semi-finals.

Comment: Semis necessitates training. :-)

Comment: why not remove "S" from finals as well?

Answer (score 0):

another version:

If we don’t train hard enough **now**, we won’t even make it **to** the semi-final**s** next year.

Answer (score -3):

One way to shorten the following sentence without losing the meaning would be to use some AI tool.

The way to do this would be to open up your favorite AI application and use the following prompt: *Please shorten the following sentence without losing its meaning. If we don't train hard enough this year, we won't even be able to make it into the semi-final next year.*

And the result might read something similar to the sentence below.

> Insufficient training this year will prevent us from reaching next year's semi-final.